# Array of objects iteration to get key and value

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

I have an array of objects. I want to efficiently extract keys and its value out of it.

Example:

```
let data = [{'Car':'Honda'}, {'car':'Volvo'}];
```

I want car as key and its values separately. How I can achieve it in efficient manner (even using lodash)?

Expected output will be:

```
key : Car  value : Honda
key : car  value : Volvo
```

Comment: What is expected output? keys and values in which format? in array, in combined object?

Comment: What is your expected output? What have you tried so far? We can't help you if you don't show your work.

Comment: do you mean something like this? `data.map(Object.entries);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and access the key and the value of properties for each object in question.

```js
let data = [{
  'Car': 'Honda',
  'hello': 'hi'
}, {
  'car': 'Volvo'
}];

data.forEach((obj) => {
 Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    console.log("key : " + key + " - value : " + obj[key]);
  });
});
```

**lodash snippet**

```js
let data = [{
  'Car': 'Honda',
  'hello': 'hi'
}, {
  'car': 'Volvo'
}];

_.forEach(data, (obj) => {
 _.forEach(Object.keys(obj), (key) => {
    console.log("key : " + key + " - value : " + obj[key]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is what i am also doing, but i need something more efficient. Can you give me some example with use of lodash?

Answer (score 1):

`Object.entries` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
const newArray = data.map((item) => Object.entries(item));
// [[['Car', 'Honda']], [['car', 'Volvo']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries(obj)` to iterate over the keys and values.

```
data.forEach((obj) => 
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => 
console.log(key, value)));
```

```js
let data = [{
  'Car': 'Honda',
  'hello': 'hi'
}, {
  'car': 'Volvo'
}];

data.forEach((obj) => 
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => 
console.log(key, value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple way to do it would be:

```js
var data = [{
  'Car': 'Honda'
}, {
  'Car': 'Volvo'
}];

var j = 0;
var carNames= [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
   var nameOfCar = data[i];
   if(nameOfCar.hasOwnProperty('Car')){
      carNames[j] = nameOfCar['Car'];
      j++;
   }
}


console.log(carNames);
```

Comment: I wont call this a 'plain and simple way' though

Comment: @aloisdg Why not? OP does not know to loop through an array. To understand for each loop as a novice is difficult, but with for loop it's much easier.

Comment: I dont know what OP is looking for and I dont know OP's background.